# How to receive more data.values by using an ajax-call?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

I have an asp file which are called with an Ajax-call and I want to receive to values a string (response) and an integer (iNumberOfSomething). The "response" value already works. But how can I add the integer-value to my ajax-call, so I can use the integer-value?

```
myAjax.asp
...
sSQL = "dbo.MyFunction"

set oRs = MyFunction(sSQL)

if not oRs.eof then
    iNumberOfSomething = cdbl(oRs("setting"))
end if
...
response.write "MyValue"
```

My ajax-call is:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: 'myAjax.asp',
  data: {
     Value1: value.toString(),
     MyId: '<%= ID %>',
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  var sMessage = '';
  ...
  if (data == "MyValue") {
    ...
  }

  if (data.iNumberOfSomething === 1) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. You can either change your ASP script to return JSON or XML, or you can make a more simple change to return the result as a comma separated list (or tab or some other separator). Here's an example of how to do the later option.

```
myAjax.asp
...
sSQL = "dbo.MyFunction"

set oRs = MyFunction(sSQL)

if not oRs.eof then
    iNumberOfSomething = cdbl(oRs("setting"))
end if
...
response.write "MyValue,AnotherValue,YetAnotherValue" 'Changed this line
```

And your ajax-call:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: 'myAjax.asp',
  data: {
     Value1: value.toString(),
     MyId: '<%= ID %>',
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
  var sMessage = '';
  ...

  //New code added here
  var results = data.split(",");

  if (results[0] == "MyValue") {
    ...

    alert(results[1]);
    alert(results[2]);
  }

  if (data.iNumberOfSomething === 1) {
    ...
  }
```

Depending on your needs you would probably want to put some more checks in there to ensure that the correct number of values appeared.

If you want to go the JSON router then you can use something like [ASPJSON](http://www.aspjson.com/)